# CheckOut Cart MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkout, webshop

I am trying to create a checkout for the cart in my webshop project for classe.
I want that every time that your press checkout it will take from the model Clothes.Amount 1 for each product that you have in the cart session.
and then I want to clean the cart.

In cart controller I have this three functions and one other to order but it is not important for this question i think.
The error is int this lines

```
Item.Cl.Amount--;
Delete(Item.Cl.Id);
```

Here is the code

```
private int isExisting(int id)
        {
            List<Item> cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];
            for (int i = 0; i < cart.Count; i++)
            {
                if (cart[i].Cl.Id == id)
                    return i;
            }return -1;
        }
public ActionResult Delete(int idDelete)
        {
            int index = isExisting(idDelete);
            List<Item> cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];
            cart.RemoveAt(index);
            Session["cart"] = cart;

            return View("Order"); 

        }
public ActionResult CheckOut(int idCheck)
        {
            int index = isExisting(idCheck);
            if(index != -1) { 
                foreach (Item item in (List<Item>)Session["cart"]) {
                    Item.Cl.Amount--;
                    Delete(Item.Cl.Id);
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question I am unable to see which error you are getting. But just looking at your code I would think that this is the classic "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute".

In method `CheckOut` You are iterating over the item list in your session. While you're doing so you call the `Delete` method which removes an item from the list. That is simply not allowed...

If that is your issue you could change your second method to the following:

```
public ActionResult CheckOut(int idCheck)
        {
            int index = isExisting(idCheck);
            if(index != -1) { 
                foreach (Item item in ((List<Item>)Session["cart"]).ToList()) {
                    Item.Cl.Amount--;
                    Delete(Item.Cl.Id);
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```